# Не могу спарсить все название песен из блока div

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy, parse

Начинал изучать Scrapy, и всё было хорошо пока я не столкнулся с этой проблемой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал цикл где я начал перебирать все названия и ссылок песен в блоке div. Ссылок Scrapy спарсил хорошо, но название песен он не смог корректно обработать. Он спарсил название только первой музыки, а остальных не трогал.

Вот код:

```
import scrapy


class ParserSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'parser'
    allowed_domains = ['downloadmusicvk.ru']
    start_urls = ['https://downloadmusicvk.ru/audio/search?q=all']

def parse(self, response):

    for el in response.css('#w1 > div'):

        title = el.xpath('//div/div[1]/span/following::text()').get()
        link = el.css('div.row.audio.vcenter > div.col-lg-9.col-md-8.col-sm-6.col-xs-5 > span > b > a::attr(href)').get()

        yield {
            'link': link,
            'title': title
        }
```

Вот сам сайт где я парсил все эти данные: https://downloadmusicvk.ru/audio/search?q=all

Пример блока:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример сайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это ошибка или я что-то упустил?

Когда я написал:

```
title = el.xpath('//div/div[1]/span/following::text()').getall()
print(title)
```

Он вернул мне вот этот массив:

```
    [' - All the Time ', '\n', '\n\n 3:39', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', 
'\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', 'Mishlawi', ' - All Night ', 
'\n', '\n\n 2:54', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', 
'\n', '\n\n\n\n', 'Miyagi & Andy Panda', ' - All the Time ', '\n', '\n\n 
3:39', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', 
'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', 'Lil Peep', ' - Broken Smile (My All) ',
 '\n', '\n\n 4:40', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', 
'\n', '\n\n\n\n', 'Billie Eilish', ' - all the good girls go to hell ', 
'\n', '\n\n 2:48', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', 
'\n', '\n\n\n\n', 'mishlawi', ' - all night ', '\n', '\n\n 3:18', '\n', 
'\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', 
'MORGENSHTERN', " - Fuck 'Em All ", '\n', '\n\n 2:23', '\n', '\n', '\n', 
'\n', '\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', 
'\n\n\n\n', 'Real1', ' - All The Way Up (Black Lion Entertainment Records 
Remix) ', '\n', '\n\n 3:11', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n',
 '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', 'Jah Khalib', ' - All About You ', '\n', 
'\n\n 3:18', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', '\n', 
'\n\n\n\n', 'RØNIN', ' - ALL GIRLS ARE THE SAME ', '\n', '\n\n 2:02', '\n',
 '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', ' ', '\n', '\n', '«', '\n', '1', '\n', '2', 
'\n', '3', '\n', '4', '\n', '5', '\n', '»', ' ', '\n', '\n', 'Поделись', 
'\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n \n\n\n', '\n', '\n\n\n\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', 
'\n', '\n', '\n', 'Наверх', '\n', '© 2021 DownloadMusicVK · ', 'Правила', '
 · ', 'Скачать\nвидео с ВК', ' · ', 'Реклама', ' · ', 'Телеграм', '\n', 
'\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', 
'\n', 'jQuery(function ($) {\njQuery&&jQuery.pjax&&
(jQuery.pjax.defaults.maxCacheLength=0);\nvar w0_data_1 = new 
Bloodhound({"datumTokenizer":Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,"queryTokenize
r":Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,"remote":{"url":"/audio/hints?
q=%QUERY","wildcard":"%QUERY"}});\nkvInitTA(\'w0\', typeahead_307a21f9, 
[{"name":"w0_data_1","source":w0_data_1.ttAdapter()}]);\nvar w3_data_1 = new
 Bloodhound({"datumTokenizer":Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,"queryTokenizer":Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,"remote":
{"url":"https://downloadmusicvk.ru/audio/hints?
q=%QUERY","wildcard":"%QUERY"}});\nkvInitTA(\'w3\', typeahead_307a21f9, 
[{"name":"w3_data_1","source":w3_data_1.ttAdapter()}]);\n});', ' ', '\n', 
'\n', '\n', '\n', '×', '\n', 'Что-то блокирует рекламу!', '\n', '\n', '\n', 
'Чтобы скачать музыку с ВК, выключите пожалуйста расширение блокирующее 
рекламу или внесите\nэтот сайт в список исключений, или попробуйте зайти с
 другого браузера.', '\n', 'Расширения обычно находятся сверху справа в 
браузере или в разделе Дополнительные инструменты\n-> Расширения.', '\n',
 'На нашем сайте нет назойливой рекламы и сайт существует на доходы с нее,
 чтобы вы могли\nкачать музыку с ВК бесплатно.', '\n', '\n ', 'Как отключить
 блокировку рекламы?', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', "\n            
let tnSubscribeOptions = {\n                serviceWorkerRelativePath: 
'/tnServiceWorker.js',\n                block: '881504'\n            };\n  
      ", '\n', '\n', '\n            (function () {\n                var sc =
 document.createElement("script");\n                var stime = 0;\n    
            try {\n                    stime = new Event("").timeStamp.toFixed(2);\n                } catch (e) {\n         
       }\n                sc.type = "text/javascript";\n                
sc.setAttribute("data-mrmn-tag", "iam");\n                
sc.setAttribute("async", "async");\n                sc.src = 
"https://pdvacde.com/wcm/?"\n                    + "sh=" + 
document.location.host.replace(/^www\\./, "")\n                    + 
"&sth=e2df249aef11088abf1542a800217192"\n                    + 
"&m=755dfe5b31411c7fafd9ea25f3ec44ba"\n                    + "&sid=" + 
parseInt(Math.random() * 1e3) + "_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1e6) + "_" + 
parseInt(Math.random() * 1e9)\n                    + "&stime=" + stime\n   
                 + "&rand=" + Math.random();\n                if 
(document.head) {\n                    document.head.appendChild(sc);\n    
            } else {\n                    var node = 
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];\n                    
node.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, node);\n                }\n            })
();\n        ', '\n', '\n']
```

el.xpath().getall() каким то образом берет все блоки из класса w1. Типа в этой функции он работает вот так:

HTML:

```
<div class='w1'>
    <div><a>1<a></div>
    <div><a>2<a></div>
    <div><a>3<a></div>
    <div><a>4<a></div>
</div>
```

Python:

```
for el in response.xpath('//*[@id="w1"]/div'):
    print(el.xpath('a::text()'))
```

И на выход он дает все элементы повторяя 4 раза:

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

А el.xpath().get() вот так:

```
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: `title = el.xpath('//div/div[1]/span/following::text()').get()` замени `get()` на `getall()`, а потом `print(title)` сделай. и добавь в вопрос что получилось

Comment: ну так вот. если там будет список, это подтвердит мою догадку, что двойной слеш в xpath это поиск от корня все таки. вы бы вообще не парились и собирали бы списки сразу. а потом по индексам формировали результат.

Comment: Сделал правку, написал и описал @alex. Что вы теперь думаете?

Comment: ну вот подтвердилась догадка моя, xpath у тебя ищет от корня (потому что // в начале), поэтому ты и получаешь на каждую песню только первое название. щас покажу как сделай. будет чуть проще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def parse(self, response):
        titles = [x.strip() for x in response.xpath("//div[@class='list-view']//div[contains(@class, 'row')]/div[1]/text()").getall() if x.strip()]
        links = response.xpath("//div[@class='list-view']//div[contains(@class, 'row')]/div[1]/span/b/a/text()").getall()

        for i, title in enumerate(titles):
            link = links[i]
            yield {'link': link, 'title': title}
```

Вот так мне кажется проще будет.

Либо добавить точку в начало пути xpath, чтобы поиск стал относительным.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for el in response.css('#w1 > div'):
            title = el.xpath('.//div/div[1]/span/following::text()').get()
            link = el.css('div.row.audio.vcenter > div.col-lg-9.col-md-8.col-sm-6.col-xs-5 > span > b > a::attr(href)').get()

            yield {
                'link': link,
                'title': title
            }
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё разработала когда точку поставил. Извините, что не сразу отблагодарил, просто у меня сессия была

Answer (score 0):

get берет вроде только 1 запись, нужно использовать getall

Comment: ему и нужен только один элемент. человек хочет выполнить xpath относительно найденного узла.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос